# How to make python as default interpreter in vs code

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, visual-studio-code

I use windows 10 machines. whenever I open vscode and run the python program, by default it uses conda environment. I have tried many different things like selecting interpreter option in the left bottom corner, and settings like `"python.PythonPath":"C:\\Users\\Nithin K Joy\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\python.exe","python.disableInstallationCheck":false, "python.terminal.activateEnvironment": true, "python.venvPath":"C:\\Users\\Nithin K Joy\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\python.exe",`
whatever I do it still runs on conda environment. The only thing that worked is removing conda path from system env and running vs code. But that is not a ideal way to deal. Anyone please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: For me, "Python" extension saves the last selected interpreter and default settings. However, there's also a setting in Code preferences too.

Comment: But for me, that doesn't work bro..

Comment: How did you install Anaconda? By default, doesn't it become the default Python installation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add an entry for `python.defaultInterpreterPath` manually inside your **User** Settings，which is to set up a default interpreter for your applications. Restart the vscode to make the setting work.

Since `python.pythonPath` setting is being removed from all 3 scopes - User, workspace, workspace folder, more information you can refer to  [vscode-python-DeprecatePythonPath](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/wiki/AB-Experiments).

Comment: Thanks for replying. But when I add it to settings, it says "unknown configuration settings". and it didn't work.

Comment: Nope, i've tried and it works. what's your vscode version?  Make sure that you put it in User settings. then close the vscode and open a clean folder, create a .py file and you'll find the environment is activated and the interpreter is the one you selected before.

Comment: I think its problem with my VScode version is 1.4.1. Anyway I uninstalled Anaconda, its a headache for me, and now I am using jupyter notebook in vs code by using Microsoft python extension. Thank you for replying and I am happy to give upvotes(2) to you.

Comment: @Nithin K Joy That's very kind of you, thanks a lot~

Comment: Is there a workaround specifying the defaultInterpreterPath to be applied in the Workspace settings only?

Comment: @fmfreeze. No, you can select the interpreter directly and don't need to specify pythonpath.

Comment: @MollyWang-MSFT not sure what you mean. I want to be able to define a default python interpreter for each project to activate the according conda env automatically (e.g. when launching a new terminal in VSC).

Comment: @fmfreeze. Python extension seems to use the last used interpreter when you open project again, which means once you select interpreter, it will use the same one unless you change it.

Comment: @MollyWang-MSFT Thank you for your superfast response :)
After some trials it seems a workspace referred `defaultInterpreterPath` works as I expected. But as I am using VSC Remote connected via SSH to a remote machine, VSC doesn't accept any `defaultInterpreterPath` config. I am stuck to VSC version 1l50.1 currently.