# Vscode uses the other interpreter which is not the one that I selected

Tags: python, tensorflow, visual-studio-code, anaconda, vscode-python

The python interpreter that I choose is python 3.7.16(tf:conda )which is set by anaconda. And its path in my computer is F:\anaconda\envs\tf\python.exe.
In the user's setting.json , I changed the interpreter path to F:\anaconda\envs\tf\python.exe.

[image]

But when I run my code in vscode, it uses a different interpreter other than the one that I chose, and its path is F:\python \python 310\ python.exe

[image]

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63644980/how-to-make-python-as-default-interpreter-in-vs-code and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72571271/vs-code-python-envfile-does-not-seem-to-work-with-python-defaultinterpreterpa

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you are using *Code Runner* to run the code. This is incorrect, because selecting an interpreter is a feature of [**Python**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) extension, so the interpreter you choose is only valid for **Python** extensions (that is, the actual interpreter version in the lower right corner).

If there is no special requirement, please use the official extension **Python** to execute the script.

[image]

*The `Run Code` option is brought by **Code Runner***

*Code Runner* does not use the settings made for the **Python** extension, so it executes the script using the python version configured by the system environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

It is because your environment path of python is set to "F:\python \python 310\ python.exe". You have to replace this path with the path you want in your Operation System environment path.